# Should I cite logos and clip-art in my thesis?

Tags: citations, thesis, graphics

In my presentation I am using a block diagram which contains few logos (like Mathworks, visual studio) and some clip-art (like desktop, hardware board) . I got these from various random websites from Google image search. Should I  cite them??

Answer (score 3):

You should cite anything you use, and you should make sure that you have an appropriate copyright license for any material you do not own the rights to. Look for Creative Commons and other pre-licensed materials to use in your work.

Comment: The only thing I'd add to that is, "when in doubt, include a citation"! ...With one exception, if it's something like Microsoft clipart, and you got it from within your software package (e.g. PowerPoint), you don't need to cite it. Which brings up another question... why not use your software's clipart collection whenever possible?

Comment: but i can't get logo of bmw or something from that...so i need to use internet to get those extra logo. like visual studio logo. etc@BethR.

Comment: @arunkumar, must you have a BMW logo? It's generally OK in many locales to use a company's logo without permission when referring to them. No one will be confused that you are referring to them rather than implying an endorsement.

Comment: If there's an image you need that isn't in your software's clipart selection, and it's not available as a pre-licensed/open image online: You can try to select the versions of those images that contain the company's trademark (TM) symbol, or the copyright symbol (C with a circle around it), etc. -- just to show that you're aware that some sort of acknowledgement like that is expected. It looks a little more professional that way... imho.